# File Read Returning Corrupt File Endings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Recently, I built a seemingly simple text-to-char string reader but it seems to return strange text towards the end of a file.

So here's one of the files I'm trying to read:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 inputColour;

out vec4 outputColour;

void main()
{
    outputColour = vec4(inputColour, 1.0f);
}
```

It's an OpenGL shader written in GLSL, fyi. However, when I try to "read" it, it returns this:

[image: Console Output]

Note the four `2` characters at the end of the command window. When I try to compile this shader at runtime, it returns errors with some characters that aren't in the original text. I created a breakpoint and looked into it further. I ran the function and opened up the Text-Visualiser and it returned this:

[image: Text Visualiser Image]

Again, there's another 4 characters at the end of the text, `ýýýý`.

---

Here's the code of the text reader:

```
std::ifstream inputFile("foo.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
int inputFileSize;
char* buffer = "";

if (inputFile.is_open())
{
    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end); //Set the cursor to the end.
    inputFileSize = (int)inputFile.tellg(); //Set inputFileSize to the position of the cursor.
    buffer = new char[inputFileSize]; //Create the buffer and set its size to the inputFileSize.
    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); //Move the cursor to the beginning.
    inputFile.read(buffer, inputFileSize); //Read the file from the beginning.
    inputFile.close(); //Close the file
}
```

My guess is that it may have something to do with line endings being read improperly. However, I have tested with files written in Notepad++ and the internal Visual Studio editor and both have given me the same results.

I did manage to find a "workaround". That is, a really fudgey-hacky workaround that's very bad practice. Basically, you can put `[FILEEND]` and the end of any text file you read. While the code allows for both `[FILEEND]` or nothing at all, the code needs the `[FILEEND]` in order for the files to be read correctly.

```
char* fileend = std::strstr(buffer, "[FILEEND]"); //Find [FILEEND].
int actualfilelen = fileend != NULL ? std::strlen(buffer) - std::strlen(fileend) : std::strlen(buffer); //Get the length of the main content of txt file. 
//If there is no [FILEEND] then return the size of the buffer without any adjustments.
char* output = new char[actualfilelen + 1]; //Create new string with the length of the main content of txt file.
std::strncpy(output, buffer, actualfilelen); //Copy main content of buffer to output.
output[actualfilelen] = '\0'; //Add escape sequence to end of file.
delete(buffer); //Deletes the original buffer to free up memory;
```

Then we just return the `output` variable. 
I don't want to have to use the `[FILEEND]` keyword(?) at the end of my files because they instantly become less portable. One or two files with `[FILEEND]` may be okay, but if I have hundreds of files that I want to use in another project, they will all have `[FILEEND]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution but it involves using `std::string` and then converting it with `string.c_str()`.

```
std::string LoadFile(const char* FileLocation)
{
    std::ifstream fileStream;
    std::string fileOutput, currentLine;
    fileStream.open(FileLocation);
    if (fileStream.is_open())
    {
        while (!fileStream.eof())
        {
            std::getline(fileStream, currentLine);
            fileOutput.append(currentLine + "\n");
            std::cout << "> " << currentLine << "\n";
        }
    }

    fileStream.close();

    return fileOutput;
}
```

And then you would be able to find the `const char*` based equivalent of the `std::string` by doing LoadFile("C:\example.txt")**.c_str();** or by saving the `LoadFile(location)` to a new `std::string` and using the `.c_str()` on that.

Note, that `.c_str()` cannot be "returned" easily as it is a pointer to a local variable. When the function ends, that variable is deleted and the `.c_str()` becomes a null-pointer. The way I have chosen to do it is to use `.c_str()` when it's needed by a function or an API-call. In C++, it seems to save a lot of hassle when you use `std::string` instead of `char*`, especially when working with text-based files and the *C++ Standard Library*.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make sure buffer is `\0` terminated. Make it `inputFileSize+1` and terminate it after reading it.

Functions like `std::strlen(buffer)` expect it. If you tried to use it anywhere without a providing a length, it would keep reading past the end of buffer.

Also, you need to `delete[] buffer` since it was allocated with `new[]`

Comment: I have now edited my code to look like this: http://pastebin.com/rhdEHP7X While the runtime compiler now reads this perfectly fine, the text now has `íííííííí` at the end. I have tried changing the text encoding from Unicode to ANSI and that did nothing. I also tried to use a printf function instead but it displayed the exact same results. I don't understand how this is happening, as the buffer's being set to a length and outputs more? For example, one of my files has 130 characters. In the inspector, I checked that `inputFileSize` is 130, and it is. Now the buffer should be 131, but it's not.

Comment: I have also removed the `[FILEEND]` keyword on my shaders and removed the `[FILEEND]` shortener code. I cannot delete the buffer as it is the output of the function now, unless that's supposed to be "copied" to another array and be deleted.

Comment: Post a minimal and complete program with an input file. Emphasis on minimal. I should be able to gcc without editing and reproduce.

Comment: Here's some code that works with GCC. (I tested it in *CodeBlocks*) http://pastebin.com/pmZ7FzWJ I have noticed that changing the encoding of the file changes the places the strange symbols are located in the console. For example, if I encode the file with `UTF-8` instead of `UTF-8 without BOM`, the symbols appear at the start. Encoding in `ANSI` provides the same results as encoding in `UTF-8 without BOM` and *different* symbols will appear at the end. In the code I set the escape sequence to be `0`. It still provides the same results as `\0`.